# Entanglement in time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, research-level, specific-reference, quantum-entanglement

Quantum entanglement links particles through time, according to this study that received some publicity last year:

- [New Type Of Entanglement Allows 'Teleportation in Time,' Say Physicists](http://www.technologyreview.com/blog/arxiv/26270/) at [The Physics arXiv Blog - Technology Review](http://www.technologyreview.com/blog/arxiv/)
- S.J. Olson, T.C. Ralph, *Extraction of timelike entanglement from the quantum vacuum*, [arXiv:1101.2565](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2565)
- S.J. Olson, T.C. Ralph, [Entanglement between the Future and the Past in the Quantum Vacuum](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.110404), Phys. Rev. Lett. 106, 110404 (2011)

> Timelike entanglement may be regarded as a non-classical resource in a manner analogous to the spacelike entanglement that is often studied in the Minkowski vacuum, since any quantum information theoretic protocol may utilize conversion of timelike entanglement to spacelike entanglement as a step in the protocol.
>   
>   I have read all the reviews in the popular press, most of the "time-travel-discovered" type, but I am looking for more sober comments, i.e. material written by physicists who have studied the paper. What does this result *really* mean? I would appreciate pointers to reviews, comments etc.

Comment: What does "this result" in _What does this result really mean?_  mean? Do you mean the concept of "timelike entanglement" or sth else?

Comment: Piotr - yes, by "this result" I mean the general concept of timeline entanglement (particles at different times can be entangled just like particles at different locations at a given time), and the specific conclusion of Olson and Ralph:"timelike entanglement may be regarded as a non-classical resource in a manner analogous to the spacelike entanglement that is often studied in the Minkowski vacuum, since any quantum information theoretic protocol may utilize conversion of timelike entanglement to spacelike entanglement as a step in the protocol."

Answer (score 2):

I would venture that the paper is less significant than it seems, since in a universe with special relativity, what looks like a successful experimental proof of spatial entanglement to one observer will always look like a mix of space and time entanglement to another one.

Comment: Thanks Terry. If "a successful experimental proof of spatial entanglement" is defined as experimental confirmation of entanglement between two particles out of each other's light cone (in other words, if there is not enough time for the particles to have exchanged signals at the speed of light), which is an invariant, then a successful experimental proof of spatial entanglement will look the same to all observers.

Comment: [on the road] Well stated Giulio; nice clean fallacy capture, and mea culpa for creating the fallacy. I'll try again when I get a moment. SR should still have geometric implications even for this spacelike separation, but not the way I just said. (Anyone?)

Comment: Giulio: I need a diagram for this, but here goes: An entangled event has two classical terminators that within a single light cone that radiates from the point of entanglement. Both origin-to-terminator paths must remain causally isolated from the rest of the universe. One short path and one long path gives time-like separation; same-length paths gives space-like separation. _Neither case differs_ when defining the consistency relationship between the terminus points. However, to classical observers the cases are different, with time-like akin to capturing half a Stern-Gerlach population.

Comment: First, entanglement is a property of quantum states, not relativistic events (points in spacetime). Causally separated or not, but an entangled state of a composite system is entangled, and a non-entangled state is not entangled. “A mix of space and time entanglement” looks like a smooth phrase that actually means nothing.

Comment: Bell's Inequality converted the metaphysical "spooky action" debate of Bohr and Einstein into meaningful experiments with fully classical setups and outcomes. If properly selected, these setups and outcomes prove the existence of a quantum entanglement relationship between them. However, the setups and outcomes are classical events subject to the space-vs-time interpretation ambiguity of special relativity. The entanglement relationship that links and mutually influences these events must bridge the same spacetime interval between events, and so is subject to frame-dependent order-of-events.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. Does your “space-vs-time interpretation ambiguity of special relativity” means “different choices of coordinate time” and nothing more? If it does, then the discussion is not interesting for me anymore, but you might edit the answer to clarify that you did not assume any inherently meaningful “space-vs-time entanglement” definition, only college-level trivia similar to the Andromeda paradox.

Comment: Specific foliations are irrelevant. If two classical events are mutually subject to Bell’s Inequality, then a foliation that makes their separation look time-like enables that relationship to be interpreted as classical causality. However, the same relationship under a space-like foliation becomes inexplicable under classical causality. By far the simplest and most self-consistent physical interpretation of this situation is that the events are linked by a single space-time relationship, entanglement, that only appears to be “causal” or “spooky” depending on the foliation used to observe it.

Comment: could we use this kind of device :D to send information or bits to the past ? :D , so we can send a message to the past with this method or another similar method http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/physicists-prove-time-travel-possible-by-sending-particles-light-into-past-1453839

Comment: Nope! There truly is a delightfully simple relationship going on here, which is only those sets of relationships that have left no trace in the web of bits we call "history" or "classical causality" are allowed to be changed in what looks to us (from within that web of bits) like the past. So instead of a change — a real transfer of information that _changes_ the known past and so would create a paradox — all we ever get by entangling with and touching the quantum past is a surprise, a gift of a newly created past from a box that no one anywhere within the classically historical ever opened.