# Using quantum entanglement to send messages back to the past

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement, causality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entanglement in time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27641/entanglement-in-time)

I heard that there is an experiment that uses quantum entanglement to try to send messages back to the past. I am having a hard time understanding how such experiments would work theoretically.

Can anyone offer me some insights toward these types of experiment?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27641/2451

Comment: Also see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/quantum-entanglement-faster-than-speed-of-light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Perfect state distinguishability and computational speedups with
postselected closed timelike curves**

http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-011-9601-0

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.0433.pdf

....Postselection of quantum teleportation in this fashion implies that an entangled state efectively creates a noiseless quantum channel into the past.....

Answer (score 1):

My theory is if one day we can send a message to the past, somebody will obviously sent message in the past to explain they are able to send message over the time.

Today, as we know, we never receive this kind of message. So we will never able to send message in the past.

Comment: We just haven't invented the right receiving device yet :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of experiment might work like that. The only thing that comes to mind is that it could somehow exploit the superluminal speed of wavefunction collapse to transmit information. But this is, of course, impossible.

Although the collapse itself is instantaneous, it is completely random so there is no information transferred in it. The moment of transfer comes when the two parties use classical communication to compare the measurement results on both parts of the system. But this can never happen faster than with the speed of light.